# Sparse Matrix Named rows/columns in python- for Categorical features and Matrix Factorisation in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, sparse-matrix, categorical-data, matrix-factorization

In machine learning algorithms you often deal with sparse data sets eg from categorical data (eg movie names), and sparse matrices handle most of the functionality.

*Is there some library that wraps scipy.sparse matrices for machine learning use cases?*

the two main missing features that I see are:

1. named rows/columns ( ie so you can identify eg movie names rather than work with integer ids)
2. subsetting whilst preserving indices. eg if I select 2 movie ids ( rows 500 and 1000) from a large 50000 row sparse matrix, I would like to return a 50000 row sparse matrix with only row 500 and 1000 non empty, so as to preserve mappings/names.

but I suspect there are others I haven't discovered yet...